# how the memory is allocated for value type variables in a class

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class below that as a method with a value type variable.

Please can some one explain me that when I create the object of the below then then what goes on the stack and what goes on the heap?

I am interested on where the variable in `Method1` goes.

```
class A
{
    public void Method1()
    {
       int i = 10;
    }
}

A obj = new A();
obj.Method1();
```

Comment: That would probably be optimized away anyhow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You most likely don't need to know this. To you, it's important *what* the runtime does, not *how* it does it. And the runtime is free to chose any way to implement local variables. For all you know, they could be saved in a file (although doing that doesn't make much sense).

If you really want to know, in general, there are several ways how a local variable can be represented in memory:

1. No representation at all. If the runtime decides the variable can be optimized away, it can do so. This can happen if nothing ever reads from the variable, like in your code.
2. It can be in a register. If the variable is small enough to fit in a register, and the runtime decides enregistering it is efficient.
3. It can be on a stack.
4. It can be part of a class on the heap. This happens to closed over variable in a method with lambdas, iterator blocks and `async` methods of C# 5.

Answer (score 1):

The object itself goes on the heap (as it is a reference type), the reference to the class (`obj`) goes on the stack, the local variable `int i` is a value type and goes on the stack or gets optimized away or goes into a register.

But you shouldn't care about such implementation details of the .NET runtime since they could theoretically change... and coding something with an unnecessary dependency on an implementation detail is bad practice IMHO.

Comment: The local variable doesn't have to go to the stack. It can be in a register, or it can be optimized away completely.